# In Django forms.ModelChoiceField HOWTO restrict displayed choices but set one of the restricted values during cleanup

Tags: django, field, choicefield, limit-choices-to

I have a custom field which subclasses ModelMultipleChoiceField. I provide the choices to be displayed via queryset parameter. This queryset excludes certain values. My problem comes when during cleanup operation for some workflows I need to select an option which was initially excluded by the way of queryset. When I try to save this value django refuses to save it saying that it is not a valid option. On looking up the clean method for ModelMultipleChoiceField I found that it checks if the provided "value" is from within the initial queryset, which causes my dilemma.

I wanted to know if it is possible to circumvent this problem without any major hacks.

Comment: It sounds to me as though the field is doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: Right, but in one of the edge cases I need to make sure that at least some value is saved, which happens to be an erstwhile excluded choice value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django/forms/models.py:1011](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/forms/models.py#L1011) has this:

```
qs = self.queryset.filter(**{'%s__in' % key: value})
```

So it seems that if you overrode your custom field's clean() method to modify self.queryset as necessary before calling `super(MyField, self).clean(value)`, you could handle this edge case relatively cleanly.